# Android does not want to boot when I try to virtualize it with qemu on Windows 10 x64 bit

Tags: windows-10, android, qemu, intel-haxm

I would like to run Android with Qemu / Haxm on top of my Windows 10 x64 installation. For this reason I have created two batch scripts. The first one is for the installation of the iso into one hd img file,and the second one is for booting Android from the hd img file.

Android installation :

```
I:\MacOS-Haxm\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -vga vmware -m 1024 -soundhw ac97 -hda I:\MacOS-Haxm\images\hdd_android.img -boot d -cdrom I:\MacOS-Haxm\images\BlissOS.iso -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000-82545em,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:18:27 -monitor stdio -accel hax
```

Android run :

```
I:\MacOS-Haxm\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -vga vmware -m 1024 -soundhw ac97 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000-82545em,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:18:27 -hda I:\MacOS-Haxm\images\hdd_android.img -accel hax
```

I did several tries,using different android iso images,like bliss or https://www.android-x86.org/ and removing the -accel hax feature,but the final result is always the same. Android does not boot,it stucks forever on the beginning. What's the error here ? I'm using qemu version 4.2.0 and during the installation I tried to format the disk with ext4,ntfs and fat32 with and without installing the grub bootloader. I see clearly that Android has been installed on the img file because its size is bigger that at the beginning,but it does not want to start.

[android freezed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xeyb3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the size of the RAM of your android VM. Sometimes, if not enough, then it can't boot successfully.